# Export the mysql data (data in other language or having some special character ) as XLS file in php 1

Tags: codeigniter

I am exporting a file in `*.xls` format in PHP. After export, file some special charaters are in the file do you have any ideas why? My library is like this type of question mark

```
<?php

class Exportclass {

    private $filename;          
    private $headerArray;       
    private $bodyArray; 
    private $rowNo = 0; 

    function ExportXLS($filename) {  

        $this->filename = $filename;    

    }

    public function addHeader($header) {        

        if(is_array($header)) {
            $this->headerArray[] = $header; 

        } else {

            $this->headerArray[][0] = $header;          
        } 

    }

    public function addRow($row) {
        if(is_array($row)) {
            if(is_array($row[0])) {
                foreach($row as $key=>$array) {
                    $this->bodyArray[] = $array;
                }
            } else {

                $this->bodyArray[] = $row;

            }
        } else {

            $this->bodyArray[][0] = $row;       
        }
    }

    public function returnSheet() { 

        return $this->buildXLS(); 

    }

    public function sendFile() {            
        $xls = $this->buildXLS();
        header("Pragma: public");           
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");            
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$this->filename);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary");
        echo $xls;
        exit;       
    }

    private function buildXLS() {           
        $xls = pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);

        if(is_array($this->headerArray)) {

            $xls .= $this->build($this->headerArray); 

        }           

        if(is_array($this->bodyArray)) {

            $xls .= $this->build($this->bodyArray); 

        }   

        $xls .= pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);             
        return $xls;        
    }       

    private function build($array) {
        $build = '';            
        foreach($array as $key=>$row) {
            $colNo = 0;
            foreach($row as $key2=>$field) {
                if(is_numeric($field)) {

                    $build .= $this->numFormat($this->rowNo, $colNo, $field);

                } else {

                    $build .= $this->textFormat($this->rowNo, $colNo, $field);

                }

                $colNo++;

            }

            $this->rowNo++;
        } 

        return $build;
    }

    private function textFormat($row, $col, $data) { 

        $data = utf8_decode($data);             
        $length = strlen($data);            
        $field = pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $length, $row, $col, 0x0, $length);
        $field .= $data;            return $field; 

    }

    private function numFormat($row, $col, $data) {
        $field = pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $row, $col, 0x0); 
        $field .= pack("d", $data); 
        return $field; 
        }   
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use PHPExcel http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ its the best possible solution to export excel files in PHP.